# having trouble opening a csv file in web2py

Tags: python, csv, web2py

I'm working on a project in web2py where I need to upload a csv file to a database, then take the information that is in that file and do something with it. I am able to upload a csv file, and in the database I can click on this file, open it, and physically read it, but when I try to open and read it in the controller it doesn't work.

The code in my controller that causes the error looks like this:

```
csvfile = open(form.vars.csv, 'r')
```

the error is "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'datab.csv.aae72db13bc450af.637376746573742e637376.csv'
"

why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the form has been processed, the upload field in the database, and therefore `form.vars.csv`, simply stores the filename, not the full file path. Rather than manually constructing the full file path and calling `open`, more simply you can just do:

```
filename, csvfile = db.mytable.csv.retrieve(form.vars.csv)
```

When passed a file name, the `.retrieve` method of an upload field object returns the original (untransformed) file name as well as the open file object.

See http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#More-on-uploads.